# How to fix/avoid concat's encoding scramble on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the situation: I have a table named "product", with a field named "code" (`integer`) and one named "name" (`varchar`). The `varchar` field is encoded with utf8, which is the right encoding. All is well and good so far.

The problem begins because I have to constantly  `concat` the "code" and "name" fields. It happens very often, and with a lot of rows. Concatting these for some reason scrambles the encoding of the `concat` result, causing funny characters to appear on screen. This in itself is fixable, by adding a `cast` to `char` in the "name" field during concat, but I fear it may cause performance issues as the system scales, since I'm calling a function on every single row of the result sets.

Is there anything I can do to my "product" table to eliminate the need for constant casting? Perhaps configuring MySQL to always select a specific encoding for its concat results?

MySQL version: 5.0.51a. Sadly I can't update it.

Create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id_product int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    code int(8) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
    id_unit int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id_product),
    KEY id_unit (id_unit),
    CONSTRAINT product_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_unit) REFERENCES unit (id_unit) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26
```

The query that results in scrambled encoding is:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(code, ' - ', name)
FROM product
```

I created a view with said query and it states (on phpMyAdmin) that the resulting column is a varbinary without any encoding. Perhaps that is the cause of the problem?

Comment: This is not normal, I've never had such problems. Please add version number, create table statement, sample data and your query.

Comment: @fancyPants Added info

Comment: Each database can have it's own default encoding, perhaps that database has an odd encoding

Comment: Your MySQL version is from 2008-01-11. Don't you think it's time to update by now? Also you're missing some information. Where did you see / set the information that the encoding is utf-8? And sample data and query would also be nice.

Comment: @fancyPants sadly the decision to update MySQL isn't mine, also when I enter the database via phpMyAdmin it shows that the encoding for that field and table are utf-8.

Comment: I have never experienced this and an explanation for me is that your 2 columns are encoded differently: `code` encoded with your database default (not utf8), and `name` in utf8, which is causing  the problem with concat as you have a mix of encoding in the same field. The CAST re-encode every char which solves the problem. You could validate this hypothesis by creating another table with a similar structure but the  `code` column also encoded as utf8. Copy a few records into it and try the concat.